# Unit test of Dataprovider in .Net

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have runned into to the issue regarding unit test of dataprovider's. What are the best way to implement that. 
One solution would be to insert something into the database and read it to make sure that it's as expected. And then removing it again. But this requires more coding. 
The other solution is to have an extra database, which i could test against. This also requires alot of work to implement it. 
What are the correct way to implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, what you are describing is called integration testing. Integration testing is something you should definitely do but it's good to understand the differences.

- A unit test tests an individual piece of code without any dependencies. Dependencies are things like a database, file system or a web service but also other internal classes that are complex and require their own unit tests. Unit tests are made to run very fast. Especially when performing test driven development (TDD) you  want your unit tests to execute in the order of milliseconds.
- Integration tests are used to test how different components work together. If you have made sure through unit tests that your business logic is correct, your integration tests only have to make sure that all connections between different elements are in place. Integration tests can take a long time but you have fewer of them than unit tests.

I wrote a blog post on this some time ago that explains the differences and shows you ways to remove external dependencies while unit testing: [Unit Testing, hell or heaven?](http://wouterdekort.blogspot.nl/2012/03/unit-testing-hell-or-heaven.html).

Now regarding, your question. When running integration tests against a database you have a couple of options:

- Use delta testing. This means that at the beginning of your test you record the current state of your database. For example, you store that are now 3 people in the people table. Then in your test you add one person and verify that there are now 4 people. in the database. This can be used quite effectively in simple scenarios. However, when your project grows more complex this is probably not the way to go.
- Use a transaction around your unit tests. This is an easy way to make sure that your tests don't leave any data behind. Just start a new transaction (using the TransactionScope class in the .NET Framework) at the beginning of the test. As long as you don't complete the transaction, all changes will be rolled back automatically.
- Use a new database for each test. Using `localdb` support in Visual Studio 2012 and higher, this can be done relatively fast.

I've chosen for the transaction scope a couple of times before and it worked quite well. One thing that's very important when writing integration tests like this is to make sure that your tests don't depend upon eachother. They need to run in whatever order the test runner decides on.

You should also make sure to avoid any 'magic numbers'. For example, maybe you know that your database contains 3 people so in your test you add one person and then assert that there are four in the database. For readers of your tests (which will be you in a couple of days, weeks or months) this is very hard to understand. Make sure that your tests are self explaining and that you don't depend on external state that's not obvious from the test.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot unit test external dependencies like database connections. There is a good post [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/119166/unit-testing-external-dependencies) about why this is the case. In short: external dependencies should be tested, but that's integration tests, not unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you do write intergration test when you call your database from code. If you want to write unittest, you should have a look at mocking frameworks.